# 既存システムをDocker化する方法

Tags: linux, docker

既に稼働してるWebアプリケーションをそのままDocker化(イメージを作成)したいと思ってるのですが、どのようにすれば良いでしょうか？
クリーンなOSのイメージを使いそこに稼働中のWebアプリケーションと同じ構成をつくっていくべきか、何かDocker化するコマンドがあるのか、未だ理解できずにおります。
どなたかご存知の方いらっしゃればご教示ください。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

dockerコンテナはDockerfileにシステムに必要なコマンドなどを明記すれば、
ワンライナーで作成する事も可能です。

まずは既存のWebアプリケーションを作成した時のコマンドをDockerfileに
記述、ビルドして同等の環境を作る事から始めて見られてはいかがでしょうか？

Dockerのビルド、コンテナ作成などは下記が参考になります。
[Dockerfileとdocker buildコマンドでDockerイメージの作成](http://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/1407/08/news031.html)
[DockerfileからのDockerイメージの作成](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E39368_01/b71105/section_svq_n2z_fp.html)